# Importance of drop of water according to scriptures?

Tags: scripture, panchabhoota

Water is one of the panchabhutas for the survival of all living beings. Many people say that water is precious and not even a single drop of water should be wasted as each and every drop of water is important and also every drop should be used purposefully. Some say that the water wasted by an individual will reflect in reducing one's own wealth.

Is it true? According to scriptures, What are the consequences?